# 'No package protobuf-devel available' error on centos 7

Tags: protocol-buffers, yum

I tried to use yum to install protobuf-devel on CentOS7, but it gives me this error:

```
No package protobuf-devel available
```

I didn't change yum resources, just use a proxy of my company, can I fix this problem rather than installing protobuf via source?

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
wget http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/protobuf/2.5.0/10.el7.centos/x86_64/protobuf-2.5.0-10.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
wget http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/protobuf/2.5.0/10.el7.centos/x86_64/protobuf-devel-2.5.0-10.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
wget http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/protobuf/2.5.0/10.el7.centos/x86_64/protobuf-compiler-2.5.0-10.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum -y install protobuf-2.5.0-10.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm \
protobuf-compiler-2.5.0-10.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm \
protobuf-devel-2.5.0-10.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same error. The following approach solved my problem.

```
sudo wget http://protobuf.googlecode.com/files/protobuf-2.5.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf protobuf-2.5.0.tar.bz2
cd protobuf-2.5.0/
./configure
```

Please read the output to see which all libraries you are missing. In my case, I ran the following commands to handle the missing things.

```
sudo yum install glibc-headers
sudo yum install gcc-c++
```

Now, let us compile and install it.

```
make
sudo make install
```

In order to verify the installation, type:

```
protoc --version
# Should give as output: libprotoc 2.5.0
```

Source: https://leveragebigdata.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/install-protocol-buffer-2-5-0/

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error and installing below packages resolved the issue:

```
yum install https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/Packages/protobuf-compiler-2.5.0-8.el7.x86_64.rpm

yum install https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.7.1908/os/x86_64/Packages/protobuf-devel-2.5.0-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
```